# Create a Function to update a Table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pug

I am trying to write a function that is used on `ng-change` in the Pug file in the select Drop down.

This function needs to update the table (id = availableFlight) to show a list of all flights where the destination matches the one selected from the dropdown list.

This using Angular which I haven't used much before and the HTML is PUG.

Here is what I have so far

JS file:

```
angular.module("app",[]).controller("myFlight",function($scope){

  $scope.destinations = ["Florida", "New York", "Venice"];

  $scope.flights = [
      {
        company: "British Airways",
        company: "EasyJet",
        company:  "Virgin"

      },
      {
        destination: "Florida",
        destination: "New York",
        destination: "Venice"
      },
      {
        class: "Economy",
        class: "Business",
        class: "Business"
      },
      {
        price: "£2000",
        price: "£4000",
        price: "£6000"
      },
      {
        airMiles: "3000",
        airMiles: "1200",
        airMiles: "9000"
      }

    ];


    // the function I am trying to create -

    $scope.updateTable = function(){


  }

  });
```

Here is the PUG file -

```
div(ng-app='app', ng-controller='myFlight')
  .container
    h1 My Flight
    h3 Select a destination:
    select(ng-model="selectedName" name="destinationList" id='destinationList' ng-change='updateTable()' ng-options="destination for destination in destinations") 
      option(value='FL') Florida
      option(value='NY') New York
      option(value='VCE') Venice
    table.table(id='availableFlight')
      thead
        tr
          th Destination
          th company 
          th class 
          th price 
          th airMiles 

      tbody(ng-repeat='flight in destinationfilter' ng-show='destinationfilter')
        tr

          td {{flight.destination}}
          td {{flight.company}}
          td {{flight.class}}
          td {{flight.price | currency:"£"}}
          td {{flight.airMiles}}
          td
            a
              i.fas.fa-long-arrow-alt-right(ng-click='selectedFlight(flight)')


    h1 Flight Selected

      h5 {{flightSummary.destination}}
      p Company: {{flightSummary.company}}
      span how many passengers : 
      input(id="number" min=1 type="number" ng-model='howMany' ng-change='updatePrice()')
      p total price {{priceTotal |currency:"£"}}
```

Any help would be really appreciated.
Many thanks

Comment: Read up on basic JavaScript first. An object may contain unique keys only

Comment: You really should, using angular is much more fun if you know javascript already. Also, since it seems that you're just starting using angular - you're using version 1, the current version is 8 though

Comment: Yeah, I am doing an exercise using version 1, so I want to complete it using version 1 not 8. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is structured incorrectly, this will lead to many downstream issues that will force you to rewrite it even if you could get this working now.

If you structure it like this you'll have a much easier time with your loops/access:

```
[
      {
        company: "British Airways",
        destination: "Florida",
        class: "Economy",
        price: "£2000",
        airMiles: "3000",
      },
      {
        company: "EasyJet",
        destination: "Venice"
        class: "Business",
        price: "£4000",
        airMiles: "1200"
      }
]
```

You can then use Angular [filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter) to limit the data to only what you want.

Also note that this is case sensitive, and the entry in your original post `Company` is not equivalent to `company` - this will certainly cause errors later.

Comment: Thats great thank you so much for helping me out with the structure of the JSON. Any advice on the function I am trying to write at the bottom of the JS file (scroll to the bottom) that updates the table (id = availableFlight) to show a list of all flights where the destination matches the one selected from the dropdown list?

Comment: Recommending filters is not good. They destroy performance and shouldn't be used. https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Comment: @chrispbacon that's nice but (1) this question is about AngularJS v1 not the newer one that you link to and (2) it's obvious that the OP is trying to learn and not developing a highly scalable production app.

Comment: @devcoder yes, look into Angular filters as I suggested

Comment: so I can use a filter in a function to update the table to show the list of all flights where the destination matches the one selected from the dropdown?

Comment: Correct, take a look at the filter docs or search for "angularjs filter tutorial"